# How to query Firebase database with order by priority and shallow parameter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that I am using to get an array by priority, but I only want a shallow copy, not all the data underneath. Here is my query:

```
    firebase.database().ref('nodeX').child(userId).orderByPriority()
```

Is there anyway to get the shallow parameter working in this format or do I need to craft a REST call?

I am using Firebase 3

Comment: Can you keep duplicate shallow data in another node? We've done that with several projects and it's a little bit more code but it makes it very efficient to load in a ton of nodes without all of the underlying data taking up bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase SDKs will always load complete nodes. They have no way to shallowly load the data.

The only way to get shallow data is through the Firebase REST API.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Frank, always appreciated!